# Coffeescript --watch switch not working with node 0.4.7

Tags: node.js, heroku, coffeescript

The --watch directive to the coffeescript compiler doesn't work with node.js 0.4.7. How to fix?

(Node 0.4.7 is currently required for deployment on Heroku.)

Comment: I'm curious: Why are you running `coffee --watch` on Heroku, rather than on your development machine?

Comment: Trevor - I'm not using coffee --watch on Heroku. I'm using node 0.4.7 locally.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fs.watch method in node.js 0.4.7. Replace the watch function at line 198 in command.js with the following:

```
watch = function(source, base) {
return fs.stat(source, function(err, prevStats) {
  if (err) throw err;
  return fs.watchFile(source, function(curr, prev) {
    return fs.stat(source, function(err, stats) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (stats.size === prevStats.size && stats.mtime.getTime() === prevStats.mtime.getTime()) {
        return;
      }
      prevStats = stats;
      return fs.readFile(source, function(err, code) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return compileScript(source, code.toString(), base);
      });
    });
  });
});
};
```

Comment: There's an open pull request to support both: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/1846

Comment: Update: The above pull request has been closed; `coffee` will not support `fs.watchFile`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade to Node 0.6, try [Jitter](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/jitter). It's a single-purpose command line utility that does what `coffee -cw` did before CoffeeScript 1.1.3. Plus it has a few little extras, like Growl notifications when compilation fails.

Comment: Thanks Trevor - Jitter looks good, I'll give it a try. Unfortunately the name is in conflict with an established programming product that I've worked on! I wonder if you've seen it before: http://cycling74.com/products/max/video-jitter/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a watchscript I wrote after having same experience with coffeescript -w option not working. It finds and watches .coffee, .less, .jade files for change and triggers their corresponding compilers in response. Generates colored output for easy detection of when the compilation failed.

```
/*
* Tested on node 0.6, Ubuntu
*/
#!/usr/bin/node

COLOR_GREEN="\033[01;32m"
COLOR_RED="\033[01;31m"
COLOR_YELLOW="\033[01;33m"
COLOR_BLUE="\033[01;34m"
COLOR_NORMAL="\033[00m"

var fs = require('fs');

var coffeescript, jade, less;
try {
  coffeescript = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script'); // after npm -g install coffee-script
} catch(e) {
  console.log(COLOR_RED,String(e),COLOR_NORMAL);
}

try {
  jade = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/jade'); // after npm -g install jade
} catch(e) {
  console.log(COLOR_RED,String(e),COLOR_NORMAL);
}

try {
  less = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/less'); // after npm -g install less
} catch(e) {
  console.log(COLOR_RED,String(e),COLOR_NORMAL);
}

console.log(
  'Watch Support',
  (coffeescript ? COLOR_GREEN : COLOR_RED),' coffeescript ',COLOR_NORMAL,
  (jade ? COLOR_GREEN : COLOR_RED),' jade ',COLOR_NORMAL,
  (less ? COLOR_GREEN : COLOR_RED),' less ',COLOR_NORMAL
);

var compile = function (fname) {
  var source = fs.readFileSync(fname).toString();
  try {
    if(/\.jade$/.test(fname)) {

      var html = jade.compile(source,{pretty:true})();
      var htmlfname = fname.replace(/\.jade$/,'.html');
      fs.writeFileSync(htmlfname, html);
      console.log(COLOR_GREEN,'Success ',fname,new Date(),COLOR_NORMAL)

    } else if(/\.coffee$/.test(fname)) {

      var js = coffeescript.compile(source);
      var jsfname = fname.replace(/\.coffee$/,'.js');
      fs.writeFileSync(jsfname, js);
      console.log(COLOR_GREEN,'Success ',fname,new Date(),COLOR_NORMAL)

    } else if(/\.less$/.test(fname)) {

      var lessparser = new(less.Parser);
      var cssfname = fname.replace(/\.less$/,'.css');
      lessparser.parse(source, function (e, tree) {
        if(e) {
          console.log(COLOR_RED,'Failed ',fname,String(e),COLOR_NORMAL);
        } else {
          fs.writeFileSync(cssfname, tree.toCSS());
          console.log(COLOR_GREEN,'Success ',fname,new Date(),COLOR_NORMAL)
        }
      });

    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(COLOR_RED,'Failed ',fname,String(e),COLOR_NORMAL)
  }
}

var walk = function(dir, done) {
  var results = [];
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    var pending = list.length;
    if (!pending) return done(null, results);
    list.forEach(function(file) {
      file = dir + '/' + file;
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          walk(file, function(err, res) {
            results = results.concat(res);
            if (!--pending) done(null, results);
          });
        } else {
          results.push(file);
          if (!--pending) done(null, results);
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

function main() {
  if(process.argv.length > 2) {
    dirName = process.argv[2];
  } else {
    dirName = '.';
  }

  stats = fs.statSync(dirName);

  if(stats.isDirectory()) {

    walk(dirName,function (err, files) {
      var watching = 0;
      files.forEach(function (fname) {
        if(/\.coffee$|\.less$|\.jade$/.test(fname)) {
          fs.watchFile(fname,{persistent:true,interval:500},
            function (cur,prev) {
              if(cur.mtime.getTime() != prev.mtime.getTime()) {
                compile(fname);
              }
            }
          );
          watching++;
        }
      }); 
      if(watching) {
        console.log('Watching '+watching+' file(s) in '+
          COLOR_YELLOW+dirName+COLOR_NORMAL);
      } else {
        console.log('No coffee/jade/less files found to watch');
      }
    });
  } else {
    // It's a file
    var fname = dirName;
    if(/\.coffee$|\.less$|\.jade$/.test(fname)) {
      fs.watchFile(fname,{persistent:true,interval:500},
        function (cur,prev) {
          if(cur.mtime.getTime() != prev.mtime.getTime()) {
            compile(fname);
          }
        }
      );
      console.log('Watching '+COLOR_YELLOW+fname+COLOR_NORMAL);
    } else {
      console.log('No coffee/jade/less files found to watch');
    }
  }
}

main();
```

If you prefer gist: https://gist.github.com/3083080